# What is the difference between hydroxyl, hydroxide and hydroxy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

Is there any difference between hydroxide, hydroxyl, and hydroxy used in chemistry or are they all the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Hydroxide** - Hydroxide is a diatomic anion with chemical formula $\ce{OH-}$. It consists of a hydrogen and an oxygen atom held together by a covalent bond, and carries a negative electric charge.

**Hydroxyl radical**- {**hydr**o- + **oxy**(gen) + -**yl** + **radical**} - The hydroxyl radical, •OH, is the neutral form of the hydroxide ion (OH<sup>-1</sup>). It is the monovalent group -OH which contains hydrogen and oxygen. The suffix -yl indicates it's a radical just like carbonyl.

**Hydroxy or hydroxy group**: A hydroxy or hydroxy group is the entity with the formula $\ce{-OH}$. It contains oxygen bonded to hydrogen. **Hydroxy** is also prefix which means containing hydroxyl group.